# Combinatorics Question Help; # of ways to choose 4 distinct officials from a city?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

there are $n \ge 4$ people in a city. And the city has its officials, consisting of 1 mayor and 3 vice-mayors. The entire board consists of 4 distinct students. Prove that by counting. In 2 different methods, count the number of ways to choose a board of officials

$$n \binom{n-1}{3} = (n-3)\binom{n}{3}$$

Any tips on two ways to help me started? I am stuck on this question and just need some starting help!

Comment: Can you go to the definition $\binom{n}{k}$ = $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$?

Comment: Rolled back destructive edit.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this: you can either choose the mayor first, THEN choose the vice-mayors, OR choose the vice-mayors first and THEN choose the mayor. Do you see how these give the two expressions you gave above?